# XSTL filter with element content

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm trying to optimize an xsl because it takes too long to modify my data.

My sourcedata (which I can't modify) looks like:

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <prodid>12345</prodid>
        .....
    </proudct>
    <product_group_map>
       <prodid>12345</prodid>
       <groupid>2435</groupid>
    </product_group_map>
</catalog>
```

I want to get these groupIds in place with the product. What I have done till now looks like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="id"><xsl:value-of select="prodid"/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="grId">
    <xsl:for-each select="../product_group_map">
        <xsl:if test="prodid = $id">
            <xsl:value-of select="groupid"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- the actual print of the values -->
<xsl:value-of select="concat( $id, $separator, $grId)"/>
```

So the process runs O^2. For 7 million products that's not ok. Is there a way to match the desired groupId somehow else?
I think of something like: If the xml would look like this

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <prodid>12345</prodid>
        .....
    </proudct>
    <product_group_map prodId="12345">
       <groupid>2435</groupid>
    </product_group_map>
</catalog>
```

I could use the select like this:

```
<!--allready in product with the path -->
<xsl:variable name="id"><xsl:value-of select="prodid"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="groupid"><xsl:value-of select="../product_group_map[@prodid = $prodId]/groupid"/></xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's inefficient to have an `xsl:variable` containing just a `value-of`, you're better putting the select expression on the `xsl:variable` itself.  Secondly, you can do the same thing you suggest for attributes with your current setup where `prodid` is an element

```
<xsl:variable name="groupid" select="../product_group_map[prodid = $id]/groupid" />
```

But it may be more efficient to define a *key* (outside any templates)

```
<xsl:key name="groupByProduct" match="prod_group_map/groupid" use="../prodid" />
```

and then you can find the group ID simply using

```
<xsl:variable name="groupid" select="key('groupByProduct', $id)" />
```

Note that if the same `prodid` is linked to several different group ids by different `product_group_map` elements, then the resulting `$groupid` variable will be a node set containing all the matching `groupid` elements.